# SQL Procedures and PHP connection to SQL server

Tags: php, sql

I have a website that uses a SQL db and some of the procedures are not working.

I upgraded my db with a new one and the procedures are not the same. My old db works, but on my new one a procedure doesn't want to execute.

Here are the errors

> Account Pane
>
> Warning: odbc_exec() [function.odbc-exec]: SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Procedure or function
>   'Website_Login_GetAccountData' expects parameter '@i_Password', which
>   was not supplied., SQL state 37000 in SQLExecDirect in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Web\account.php on line 293
>
> Warning: odbc_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Web\account.php on line 294
>       Account does not exist.

And this is my procedure from the SQL server database:

```
USE [atum2_db_account]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Website_Login_GetAccountData]    Script Date: 7/13/2016 1:14:22 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO



CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Website_Login_GetAccountData]
    @i_AccountName          VARCHAR(20),
    @i_Password             VARCHAR(32)
AS
    DECLARE @AccountCount INT = (SELECT COUNT(td_Account.AccountUniqueNumber) FROM [atum2_db_account].[dbo].[td_Account] WHERE td_Account.AccountName = @i_AccountName)
    DECLARE @DoubleLogin int =(SELECT td_Account.ConnectingServerGroupID from [atum2_db_account].[dbo].[td_Account] WHERE td_Account.AccountName=@i_AccountName)
if(@DoubleLogin >0)
BEGIN
    SELECT 99 AS [AccountCount] -- Double login !
        RETURN
END
    IF(LEN(@i_Password) <> 32 OR LOWER(@i_Password) LIKE '%[^0-9a-f]%')
    BEGIN
        SELECT 4 AS [AccountCount] -- Wrong Password Lenght
        RETURN
    END

    DECLARE @CurrentPassword VARCHAR(32) = (SELECT td_Account.Password FROM [dbo].[td_Account] WHERE td_Account.AccountName = @i_AccountName)
    IF(@CurrentPassword IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        SELECT 6 AS [AccountCount] -- Invalid Accountname
        RETURN
    END

    IF(@CurrentPassword <> @i_Password)
    BEGIN
        SELECT 5 AS [AccountCount] -- Invalid Password
        RETURN
    END

    DECLARE @Date DATETIME =(SELECT TOP 1 td_BlockedAccounts.EndDate
    FROM [atum2_db_account].[dbo].[td_BlockedAccounts]
    WHERE td_BlockedAccounts.AccountName = @i_AccountName and td_BlockedAccounts.EndDate > GETDATE()
    ORDER BY td_BlockedAccounts.EndDate DESC)

    IF (@Date IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SELECT 3 AS [AccountCount]
        RETURN
    END

    ELSE IF (@AccountCount = 1)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @AccountCount AS [AccountCount], td_Account.AccountUniqueNumber, td_Account.AccountType, td_Account.WarPoint, td_Account.CashPoint, td_Account.VoteCount ,DATEADD(HOUR, 4, td_AccountVote.LastVote1) AS [NextVote1] ,DATEADD(HOUR, 4, td_AccountVote.LastVote2) AS [NextVote2] ,DATEADD(HOUR, 4, td_AccountVote.LastVote3) AS [NextVote3] ,DATEADD(HOUR, 4, td_AccountVote.LastVote4) AS [NextVote4] FROM [atum2_db_account].[dbo].[td_Account] LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[td_AccountVote] ON [dbo].[td_Account].AccountName = [dbo].[td_AccountVote].AccountName WHERE [dbo].[td_Account].AccountName = @i_AccountName
        RETURN
    END

    ELSE IF(@AccountCount <> 0)
    BEGIN
        SELECT 2 AS [AccountCount]
        RETURN
    END

    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT 0 AS [AccountCount]
        RETURN
    END



GO
```

And this is the line from the PHP code with the error:

```html
<?php
 if(!defined('USE_INDEX')) exit;
?>
<h1>Account Panel</h1>
<?php 
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
$time = date("l dS of F Y h:i:s A"); 
$script = "User-CP";
$fp = fopen ("Log/SQL_Injection.txt", "a+"); 
$hackfound = false;
$sql_inject_1 = array(";","'","%",'"'); #Whoth need replace 
$sql_inject_2 = array("", "","","&quot;"); #To wont replace 
$GET_KEY = array_keys($_GET); #array keys from $_GET 
$POST_KEY = array_keys($_POST); #array keys from $_POST 
/*begin clear $_GET */ 
for($i=0;$i<count($GET_KEY);$i++) { 
 $real_get[$i] = $_GET[$GET_KEY[$i]]; 
 $_GET[$GET_KEY[$i]] = str_replace($sql_inject_1, $sql_inject_2, htmlspecialchars($_GET[$GET_KEY[$i]])); 
 if($real_get[$i] != $_GET[$GET_KEY[$i]]) { 
  fwrite ($fp, "IP: $ip\r\n"); 
  fwrite ($fp, "Method: GET\r\n"); 
  fwrite ($fp, "Value: $real_get[$i]\r\n"); 
  fwrite ($fp, "Script: $script\r\n"); 
  fwrite ($fp, "Time: $time\r\n"); 
  fwrite ($fp, "==================================\r\n"); 
  $hackfound = true;
 } 
} 
/*end clear $_GET */ 
/*begin clear $_POST */ 
for($i=0;$i<count($POST_KEY);$i++) { 
 $real_post[$i] = $_POST[$POST_KEY[$i]]; 
 $_POST[$POST_KEY[$i]] = str_replace($sql_inject_1, $sql_inject_2, htmlspecialchars($_POST[$POST_KEY[$i]])); 
 if($real_post[$i] != $_POST[$POST_KEY[$i]]) { 
  fwrite ($fp, "IP: $ip\r\n"); 
  fwrite ($fp, "Method: POST\r\n"); 
  fwrite ($fp, "Value: $real_post[$i]\r\n"); 
  fwrite ($fp, "Script: $script\r\n"); 
  fwrite ($fp, "Time: $time\r\n"); 
  fwrite ($fp, "==================================\r\n"); 
  $hackfound = true;
 } 
}
/*end clear $_POST */ 
fclose ($fp); 
?>
<?php
 if(empty($_GET['a']))
  $_GET['a'] = '';
 if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
 {
  // Logged in
  if($_GET['a'] == 'logout')
  {
   session_destroy();
   echo '<div style="text-align: center;">'
    .'<span style="color: green;">Logout successful!</span><br />'
    .'Please wait 3 seconds.<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=index.php?site=home">'
    .'</div>';
  }
  elseif($_GET['a'] == 'changepwd')
  {
   if(isset($_POST['pwd_submit'])) {
    //Fehlersuche
    $errors = array();
    if(empty($_POST['pwd_old']) || empty($_POST['pwd_new']) || empty($_POST['pwd_retype']))
     $errors[] = 'Fill-in all fields.';
    if(!empty($_POST['pwd_old']) && md5($pwdsalt.$_POST['pwd_old']) != $data['Password'])
     $errors[] = 'Your old password is wrong.';
    if((!empty($_POST['pwd_new']) && !empty($_POST['pwd_retype'])) && (strlen($_POST['pwd_new']) > 14 || strlen($_POST['pwd_new']) < 4))
     $errors[] = 'The new password must be 4 to 14 characters.';
    if((!empty($_POST['pwd_new']) && !empty($_POST['pwd_retype'])) && $_POST['pwd_new'] != $_POST['pwd_retype'])
     $errors[] = 'Passwords do not match!';
    if((!empty($_POST['pwd_new']) && !preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]/', $_POST['pwd_new'])) || (!empty($_POST['pwd_retype']) && !preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]/', $_POST['pwd_retype'])))
     $errors[] = 'Password has invalid characters. Just allowed: aA-zZ, 0-9';
    
    echo '<div style="text-align: center;">';
    if(count($errors) > 0) {
     foreach($errors as $error) {
      echo '<span style="color: red;">'.$error.'</span><br />';
     }
    } else {
     $newpwdhash = md5($pwdsalt.$_POST['pwd_new']);
     if(odbc_exec($mssql, 'exec [atum_ChangePassword] \''.mssql_escape_string($data['AccountName']).'\',\''.$newpwdhash.'\'')) {
      echo '<span style="color: green;">Your Password has successfully been changed!</span><br />';
     } else {
      echo '<span style="color: red;">Error! Please try again.</span><br />';
     }
    }
    echo '</div>';
   }
   echo '<h2>Change Password</h2>';
   echo '<form action="" method="post">
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td>Old Password:</td>
      <td><input type="password" name="pwd_old" maxlength="14" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>New Password:</td>
      <td><input type="password" name="pwd_new" maxlength="14" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Retype Password:</td>
      <td><input type="password" name="pwd_retype" maxlength="14" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="pwd_submit" value="Change PW" /></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </form>';
  } elseif($_GET['a'] == 'changemail') {
   if(isset($_POST['mail_submit'])) {
    $checkemail = odbc_exec($mssql, 'exec [atum_CheckEmailExist] \''.mssql_escape_string($_POST['mail_new']).'\'');
    //Fehlersuche
    $errors = array();
    if(empty($_POST['mail_old']) || empty($_POST['mail_new']))
     $errors[] = 'Fill-in all fields.';
    if(!empty($_POST['mail_old']) && $_POST['mail_old'] != $data['email'])
     $errors[] = 'Your old E-Mail is wrong.';
    if(!empty($_POST['mail_new']) && !preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/', $_POST['mail_new']))
     $errors[] = 'Invalid e-mail address.';
    if(!empty($_POST['mail_new']) && odbc_result($checkemail, 'EmailCount') > 0)
     $errors[] = 'This e-mail address does already exist.';
    if(filter($_POST['mail_new']) == 1)
     $errors[] = 'This e-mail provider is not allowed.';
    
    echo '<div style="text-align: center;">';
    if(count($errors) > 0) {
     foreach($errors as $error) {
      echo '<span style="color: red;">'.$error.'</span><br />';
     }
    } else {
     $letters = 'abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789';
     $activationcode = substr(str_shuffle($letters), 0, 30);
     
     if(mail($_POST['mail_new'], 'RoRivals: Account Activation', 'Hello '.$data['AccountName'].'.
     
     Your link for account activation: http://www.rorivals.eu/index.php?site=activation&activationcode='.$activationcode.'
     
     Have fun.', 'From: RoRivals <'.$mail.'>')) {
      if(odbc_exec($mssql, 'exec [atum_ChangeEmail] \''.mssql_escape_string($_SESSION['user']).'\',\''.mssql_escape_string($_POST['mail_new']).'\',\''.mssql_escape_string($activationcode).'\'')) {
       echo '<span style="color: green;">Your E-Mail has successfully been changed!</span><br />';
      } else {
       echo '<span style="color: red;">Error! Please try again.</span><br />';
      }
     } else {
      echo '<span style="color: red;">Error! Please try again.</span><br />';
     }
    }
    echo '</div>';
   }
   echo '<h2>Change E-Mail</h2>';
   echo '<form action="" method="post">
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td>Old E-Mail:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="mail_old" maxlength="50" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>New E-Mail:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="mail_new" maxlength="50" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="mail_submit" value="Change Mail" /></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </form>';
  }
  elseif($_GET['a'] == 'resetchar')
  {
   if($data['ConnectingServerGroupID'] == 0) {
    odbc_exec($mssql, 'USE [atum2_db_1]');
    if(isset($_POST['reset_submit'])) {
     $characterdata = odbc_exec($mssql, 'exec [atum_GetCharacterData] \''.mssql_escape_string($_POST['reset_character']).'\'');
     $influence = odbc_result($characterdata, 'InfluenceType');
     $material = odbc_result($characterdata, 'Material');
     if($influence == 2) {
      $mapindex = '2001';
     } elseif($influence == 4) {
      $mapindex = '2002';
      odbc_exec($mssql, 'UPDATE [td_Character] SET MapIndex=\'2002\' WHERE UniqueNumber=\''.mssql_escape_string($_POST['reset_character']).'\'');
     } else {
      if($material == 0) {
       $mapindex = '2003';
      } else {
       $mapindex = $material;
      }
     }
     odbc_exec($mssql, 'exec [atum_UpdateMapindex] \''.mssql_escape_string($_POST['reset_character']).'\'');
     echo '<span style="color: green;">Your characters has successfully been resetted!</span>';
    }
    $characters = odbc_exec($mssql, 'SELECT * FROM [td_Character] WHERE AccountName=\''.mssql_escape_string($_SESSION['user']).'\' AND Race < 16000');
    $countcharacter = odbc_exec($mssql, 'SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM [td_Character] WHERE AccountName=\''.mssql_escape_string($_SESSION['user']).'\' AND Race < 16000');
    echo '<h2>Reset Character</h2>';
    if(odbc_result($countcharacter, 'count') > 0) {
     echo 'Choose Character:';
     echo '<form action="" method="post">
      <select name="reset_character">';
     while($character = odbc_fetch_array($characters)) {
      echo '<option value="'.$character['UniqueNumber'].'">'.$character['CharacterName'].'</option>';
     }
     echo '</select>
     <input type="submit" name="reset_submit" value="Reset" />
     </form>';
    } else {
     echo '<span style="color: red;">No characters available!</span>';
    }
   } else {
    echo '<span style="color: red;">Unable to reset characters!</span>';
   }
  }
  else
  {
   $accdata = odbc_exec($mssql, 'exec [atum_Website_Get_Login_Data] \''.$data['AccountName'].'\'');
   $votecount = odbc_exec($mssql, 'exec [atum_GetAccountVote] \''.$data['AccountName'].'\'');
   
   echo 'You are logged in as <b>'.$data['AccountName'].'</b>. (<a href="index.php?site=account&a=logout">Logout</a>)<br />
    You have at the moment '.odbc_result($accdata, 'CashPoint').' Credits and '.odbc_result($accdata, 'WarPoint').' WarPoints!<br />
    You did vote '.odbc_result($votecount, 'VoteCount').' times!<br />
    Do vote or donate to get credit to buy ingame great items in the Credit-Shop!<br />
    <br />
    To vote you have to click on every of the 4 buttons ,to insert the right captchas and to send them.<br />
    For every vote you get <b>150 WarPoints OR 50 Credits (1:1 Rate)</b>.<br /><br />';
   echo '<span id="voteresult"></span>';
   echo '<b>Vote:</b><br />';
   echo '<a href="javascript:votePopup(1);">Top Of Games</a> | <a href="javascript:votePopup(2);">E-JOC</a> | <a href="javascript:votePopup(3);">MMORPG-PrivateServer</a> | <a href="javascript:votePopup(4);">MMORPG-Toplist</a><br /><br />';
   echo '<b>Options:</b><br />';
   echo '<a href="index.php?site=account&a=changepwd">Change Password</a><br />';
   echo '<a href="index.php?site=account&a=changemail">Change E-Mail</a><br />';
   echo '<a href="index.php?site=account&a=resetchar">Reset Character</a><br />';
  }
 }
 else
 {
  // Logged out
  $ShowLoginForm = true;
  if(isset($_POST['login_submit'])) 
  {
   // Login Action
   echo '<div style="text-align: center;">';
   $errors = array();
   if(empty($_POST['login_id']))
    $errors[] = 'Enter a accountname.';
   if(empty($_POST['login_pw']))
    $errors[] = 'Enter a password.';
   if(!empty($_POST['login_id']) && (strlen($_POST['login_id']) > 20 || strlen($_POST['login_id']) < 4))
    $errors[] = 'The accountname must be 4 to 20 characters.';
   if(!empty($_POST['login_id']) && !preg_match('#^[a-z0-9]+$#i', $_POST['login_id']))
    $errors[] = 'Accountname has invalid characters. Just allowed: aA-zZ, 0-9';
   if(!empty($_POST['login_pw']) && (strlen($_POST['login_pw']) > 14 || strlen($_POST['login_pw']) < 4))
    $errors[] = 'The password must be 4 to 14 characters.';
   if(!empty($_POST['login_pw']) && !preg_match('#^[a-z0-9]+$#i', $_POST['login_pw']))
    $errors[] = 'Password has invalid characters. Just allowed: aA-zZ, 0-9';
   if($hackfound)
    $errors[] = 'Invalid special characters found.';
   if(count($errors) > 0) {
    foreach($errors as $error)
    {
     echo '<span style="color: red;">'.$error.'</span><br />';
    }
    unset($errors);
   }
   else
   {
    $accountdata = odbc_exec($mssql, 'EXEC [atum2_db_account].[dbo].[Website_Login_GetAccountData] \''.mssql_escape_string($_POST['login_id']).'\'');
    switch(odbc_result($accountdata, 'AccountCount'))
    {
    case 0:
     echo '<span style="color: red;">Account does not exist.</span><br />';
     break;
    case 1:
     if(md5($pwdsalt.$_POST['login_pw']) == odbc_result($accountdata, 'Password'))
     {
      $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['login_id'];
      $_SESSION['accounttype'] = odbc_result($accountdata, 'AccountType');
      $_SESSION['warpoint'] = odbc_result($accountdata, 'WarPoint');
      $_SESSION['cashpoint'] = odbc_result($accountdata, 'CashPoint');
      $_SESSION['votecount'] = odbc_result($accountdata, 'VoteCount');
      $_SESSION['lastvote'] = array( 1 => odbc_result($accountdata, 'LastVote1'),
              2 => odbc_result($accountdata, 'LastVote2'),
              3 => odbc_result($accountdata, 'LastVote3'),
              4 => odbc_result($accountdata, 'LastVote4'));
      echo '<span style="color: green;">Login successful!</span><br />'
      .'Please wait 3 seconds.<br /><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;">'
      .'<a href="index.php?site=account">Go to User Panel</a>';
      $ShowLoginForm = false;
     }
     else
     {
      echo '<span style="color: red;">Your password is wrong!</span><br />';
     }
     break;
    case 2:
     echo '<span style="color: red;">More than one account found, contact the staff-team.</span><br />';
     break;
    default:
     echo '<span style="color: red;">Generic error.</span><br />';
     break;
    }
   }
   echo '</div><br />';
  }
  if($ShowLoginForm)
  {
   // Show Login Form
  ?>
   <head>
    <script>
     jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery("#login_cp").validationEngine();
     });
    </script>
   </head>
   <form id="login_cp" action="index.php?site=account" method="post">
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td>ID:</td>
      <td><input name="login_id" id="login_id" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[noSpecialCharacters],minSize[4],maxSize[20]]" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Password:</td>
      <td><input name="login_pw" id="login_pw" type="password" class="validate[required,minSize[4],maxSize[14]]" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center; padding-top: 10px;"><input name="login_submit"  id="login_submit"  type="submit"value="Login" /></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </form>
  <?php
  }
 }
?>
```

Comment: Step 1: Read the error message.  Step 2: Identify where you attempt to do what the error message claims you're not doing.

Comment: sory i know i writte very bad but i dont know wery well english and
 i come in here to ghet anser i try al ready to do what you say  but stil saime error i try to modify the SQL procedure but saime error

Comment: Tried *how*?  The stored procedure expects two parameters, and you're supplying one parameter.  What exactly did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Your stored procedure expects two parameters:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Website_Login_GetAccountData]
    @i_AccountName          VARCHAR(20),
    @i_Password             VARCHAR(32)
AS
    --...
```

But you're supplying one parameter:

```
EXEC [atum2_db_account].[dbo].[Website_Login_GetAccountData] 'someLoginID'
```

Hence the error:

> Procedure or function 'Website_Login_GetAccountData' expects parameter '@i_Password', which was not supplied.

So you have two options:

- Supply the second parameter; or
- Remove the second parameter from the stored procedure (and modify its internal logic accordingly)

Supplying the second parameter would make your `EXEC` query look something like this:

```
EXEC [atum2_db_account].[dbo].[Website_Login_GetAccountData] @i_AccountName = 'someLoginID', @i_Password = 'somePassword'
```

Comment: stil saime error how i sai im stil a biginer i what to lerns al of this but  on mi las db i dont have tis eroor and i trei to soply the exec exacly how you explayn but the php dont  conect to that procedure abouth @i_password and sai it`s not supply but in my SQL procedure declare exacly how  supuse to be so the problem its my PHP   so if i post all php file and what its write in file u wil se have a include file like config_script.php what its all ok there .. bicouse on my server game im ablle to log in so the procedure are corect  so what to do i got new DB It`s new to me so what to do

Comment: @gabyvasile: What is the updated code and error message?  Edit the question to reflect the changes.  I can't help you unless you actually provide information about the problem.

Comment: i belive i destroy my procedure i wil remake how was the only thing i ned to do to  recode the PhP file with all i ned in bicouse the procedure are corect i got saime eroor like before i erase line from mt procedure now lock like this  http://prntscr.com/bsjde3 and the php like http://prntscr.com/bsjdvl and the eror its http://prntscr.com/bsjg9x

Comment: plse can u fix my php file i add the complete php and my procedure there bicouse i am not god at this  realy i dont what else to do just to ask help from a pro  like you and other are im stil learnig abaouth Thia  sry for my mistake writing. that wiy i come and register here for help from you guys ..please help me :S:S